# Exception handling in FitNesse

Tags: c#, .net, fitnesse

Gojko Adzic, in his book [*Test Driven .NET Development with FitNesse*](http://gojko.net/FitNesse/book/ch05s04.html), gives some basic tips on reducing the test code. There's a method called `LogIn` which, based on the username and password, returns player's id or throws an exception when there's no such registered player. Here's the initial version of the test code:

```
public class CheckLogIn : fit.ColumnFixture
{
    public string username;
    public string password;

    public int LoggedInAsPlayerId()
    {
        try
        {
            SetUpTestEnvironment.playerManager.LogIn(username, password);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is then replaced with a shorter version:

```
public class CheckLogIn : fit.ColumnFixture
{
    public string username;
    public string password;

    public int LoggedInAsPlayerId()
    {
        return SetUpTestEnvironment.playerManager.LogIn(username, password);
    }
}
```

Now the second test has an added bonus of verifying if a correct id is returned, but it doesn't allow you to check if the system rejects an unknown user/wrong password. **Is there any special value which can be used in a column to indicate an exception?** Or do I have to combine both tests to cover all scenarios? I remember, albeit vaguely at this very moment, there was some kind of unit test pattern for handling exceptions, but I'm sure somebody has already asked about it, so I don't want to duplicate. Unless the community is OK with that, then please suggest a best practice for testing such methods.

In case I'm not being clear:

Say I got one registered player: `john.doe/test123/101` (username/password/id). Two of the combinations I would want to test the system against are `john.doe/test123/101` and `john.doe/johnny/<WrongUserOrPasswordException>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fixture keywords which allow checking for exceptions:

- `error` - when an exception should be thrown during the test
- `exception` - to check for a particular exception

This was actually well explained on the [following page](http://gojko.net/FitNesse/book/ch05s05.html) of the book... My bad for not noticing it straight away. Maybe somebody will find this information useful, so I'm not deleting the question.